# SQL: Use system date to select data for column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (DBname) with 2 columns. column1 (datatype =dates) has the dates for the next 2 years. column2 (datatype = integer) some data i've assigned. How can I get SQL to select the data in column2 that corresponds with the current system date. i've tried the following without success it return a blank... I am using MySQL

```
SELECT column2 FROM DBname WHERE column1 = CURRENT_DATE
```

if i change it to

```
SELECT column2 FROM DBname WHERE column1 > CURRENT_DATE
```

it returns `column2 rowid1`

if i change it to

```
SELECT column2 FROM DBname WHERE column1 > CURRENT_DATE
```

it returns `column2 rowid3`... really confused... is it possible the problem is in the database itself??

as for the data.. i imported an excel file with the dates in column1.. i wrote the first date in and formatted it then dragged down about 2 years to populate the rest.... as for the column2 data it is just numbers i have placed in... an example would be

```
column1 1-dec-12, 2-dec-12, 3-dec-12, 4-dec-12     
column2   2,  4, 18, 19
```

Comment: What is the data type of column1?

Comment: What is the problem? "*without success*" is not a valid description of a problem. Do you get an error? Do you get incorrect results?

Comment: do your "dates" in column 1 also have times attached?

Comment: Please post some sample data... sounds like there is something you aren't mentioning

Comment: Are you sure Column 1 is DATE type?  Not VARCHAR?  DBMS's often use 2012-12-01 notation.  Copying from Excel is suspect.

Comment: pretty sure... as i imported it tho it changed to the format i listed in the write up

Comment: Can you show us the output of `SELECT * FROM dbname LIMIT 10 ;`

Comment: And please provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE dbname;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you `column1` which holds date is a **STRING**. You need first to convert it to `DATE` using `STR_TO_DATE` function,

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(column1, '%e-%b-%y') > CURDATE()
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdcf7/1)

OTHER SOURCE

- [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: put that in exactly as shown and i didn't work either... returns null

Comment: your question is too incomplete. can you post the table definition for your table? eg, `DESC yourTable` and post the result here.