# SQL newbie: Use current date as variable in SQL query

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlitemanager

I have used Excel and created 2 columns. `column1` contains DATES, `column2` contains values as INT. I have imported the table as a CSV using SQLite Manager. I am connected to the DB and have used it with success for other queries that involved text only. Now I would like to SELECT the INT in column2 that corresponds to the current date displayed in column1. Therefore, everyday when the SQL query is ran it will auto-update based on the new current date. I have used

```
SELECT column2 FROM table WHERE column1 = CURRENT_DATE
```

However, it returns null (blank, nothing), whereas if I use

```
SELECT column2 FROM table WHERE column1 > CURRENT_DATE
```

it returns the INT in column2 of rowid1, but if I use

```
SELECT column2 FROM table WHERE column1 < CURRENT_DATE
```

it returns the INT in column 2 of rowid3.

Therefore, the DB is functioning; however, the problem is it cannot associate the current system date with the right value in column1. Is it possible that the import of CSV. into SQLite has altered the datatype to VARCHAR or something other than DATE and INT?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Use system date to select data for column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009553/sql-use-system-date-to-select-data-for-column)

Comment: @JW: that other question is for MySQL, not SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not have a `DATE` data type.

Dates are typically stored as strings (CSV does not have types anyway), and to be compatible with SQLite's built-in date functions, must be in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Before exporting from Excel, ensure that all dates are formatted with this format.

Comment: this worked.... it required using custom formatting in Excel to the stated yyyy-mm-dd format... imported as CSV and query as  SELECT column2 FROM date WHERE column1 = date('now')